# How do I Open two connection strings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, console-application

I Have application developed in VB.NET. Now I need to implement new feature to that application.

So I Created method which deals with new functions. I need to call three stored procedure inside this method in which one SP is from one database and another two SP is from different database.

Now I am able to call SP by calling one connection string. But I don't know how to open two connection string and call SP present in different database.

**I have if condition like this in my code:**

```
 If application("skipCharge") Is Nothing Then
 Console.WriteLine("App charges")
 chargeApplication(cxnmarketDb, ConnectionStrings("Applications_" & siteName).ConnectionString, dtAppStart)
 Console.WriteLine()
  End If
```

Here **Applications_** is my connection string name. What I am thinking is i need to put my 2nd database connection string inside if statement. But don't know how to select both if i put inside if.

And this is the code in my method :

```
 Private Sub chargeApplication(ByRef cxnmarketDb As SqlConnection, ByVal cxnApplicationPlaceString As String, ByVal dtAppStart As Date)

        Const chargeEventText As String = "This is a text "
        Using cxnPlace As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cxnApplicationPlaceString)
            Try
                cxnPlace.Open()
            Catch exDetail As SqlException
                Console.WriteLine(" +  cxnPlace.SqlException :: " & exDetail.Message)
            Catch exDetail As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(" +  cxnPlace.Exception :: " & exDetail.Message)
            End Try

            If cxnPlace.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

                Using cmdAppList As SqlCommand = cxnPlace.CreateCommand()
                 cmdAppList.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                 cmdAppList.CommandText = "First_SP"
                 cmdAppList.CommandTimeout = 60


                 Try
                  Using sdrAppCharge As SqlDataReader = cmdAppList.ExecuteReader()
                  Do While sdrAppCharge.Read()
                  Using cmdChargeSearch As SqlCommand = cxnmarketDb.CreateCommand()
                    cmdChargeSearch.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmdChargeSearch.CommandText = "second_SP"
                    cmdChargeSearch.CommandTimeout = 60
```

Here I am able to call first_SP. But after that it is going to END statement. Because second_SP is in different connection string and it is not opened.

So how do I open two connection string here and call my Stored procedures ?

Comment: Just initialize a new variable with New SqlConnection by passing the other connection string...

Comment: @the_lotus I did as you said.Now I am able to pass two connection string but don't know it is not going inside second connection string. I have to go through logic again.